# Click executes the function only once

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with a button whose id is `calbtn`. The `form` has two `input` fields whose ids are `input1` and `input2`.

I want to check if the inputs are empty after I click `callbtn`. If the inputs are empty, then display the alert box (whose id is `failurebox`) else submit the form.
But this function is executed only once during its first time. When I click again `callbtn` does not execute the check function. If I leave either of my `input1` or `input2` empty for second time.

Please help me solve this problem. I am new to using jQuery. Please correct my below jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calbtn").on('click', function() {
        if ($("#tempsp").val() == "" || $("#temppv").val() == "")
            $("#failurebox").show();
    });// end of click function 
});
```

My HTML code is

```
<form id="newlayerform" role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tempsp" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:red">Temp Set Point</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tempsp" id="tempsp" placeholder="Enter Temp Set Point">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><b>deg.Celcius</b></div>
        </div><!--end of input group--> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="temppv" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:red">Temp Process</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="temppv" id="temppv" placeholder="Enter Temp Process">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><b>deg.Celcius</b></div>
        </div><!--end of input group--> 
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="calbtn" name="calbtn">Calculate</button>

</form>

 <div id="failurebox" class="alert alert-warning" style="display:none">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        Failure
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the problem solved.

The problem was in my alert box. I have used dismissible alert box with a close button. When I get the error for first time I was just closing my alert box which is preventing from getting the alert again when I do it for the second time.

The click function was working fine but the problem was due to the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

The form should not be submitted. Use `return false;` to stop form from submitting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calbtn").on('click', function() {
        if (!$.trim($("#input1").val()) || !$.trim($("#input2").val())) {
            $("#failurebox").show();
        } else {
            $("#failurebox").hide();
        }

    }); // end of click function 
});
```

Comment: still not working !! its not about form submission. when I am clicking the button for first time with input 1 and input 2 empty and press calbtn then it displays error alert box as expected. For the second time I enter only put text in input 1 and press callbtn. Now no error alert box not shown. ( form is not submitted in both cases, that is not a problem since I havent written the script for it yet )

Comment: @sravankumar Are you removing & then adding `calbtn` dynamically?

Comment: sorry doesnt work,  behaves same way as before. Working only first time

Answer (score 0):

Try this: jquery way of checking if an input is empty:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calbtn").on('click', function() {
        if (!$("#input1").val() || !$("#input2").val()) {
            $("#failurebox").show();

        }
    }); // end of click function 
});
```

I think I've gotten it to work using this [sqlfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mop82mtf/1/)
I did it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calbtn").click(function() {
        if (!$("#tempsp").val() || !$("#temppv").val())
        {
            $("#failurebox").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#failurebox").hide();
        }
    });// end of click function 
});
```

EDIT: my bad I made a slight mistake but fixed it now, should work now

Comment: still its checking for first time I press the button, when I press the button second time ( entering only one input ) it doesnt check.

Comment: are you sure you are not unbinding the click event somewhere? with only the code I see in your question it should work, can you add your html to the question so I can try a jsfiddle on it

Comment: what does your failurebox look like? is it a div, a label , it's not in your html

Comment: its a div ( bootstrap alert ) . Do you want me put that too

Comment: I can't close the alert (not giving me the x option to close it)

Comment: @sravankumar I think I got it